# Environment variable Settings for Linux about anaconda

Tags: linux, pycharm, environment

I code in Pycharm like this:

```
bin_path = dirname(sys.executable)
print(os.environ['PATH'])

if 'PATH' in os.environ:
    os.environ['PATH'] += ':' + bin_path
else:
    os.environ['PATH'] = bin_path
print(bin_path)
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

the outputs are :

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
/home/xiaozh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu36/bin
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/xiaozh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu36/bin
```

then i want to add "/home/xiaozh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu36/bin" as a PATH to Linux system, so that I don't have to write the code above in the later work,but the problem happened ,i do it using:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/xiaozh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu36/bin
```

in Linux ,and check the "PATH" by :

```
export
```

and i can see the new PATH variable as following:

```
declare -x PATH="/home/xiaozh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu36/bin:
```

but the outputs after running the first part codes in Pycharm are same as:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
/home/xiaozh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu36/bin
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/xiaozh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu36/bin
```

then i code in Linux use same codes,the outputs are different,Show me my new PATH in the variable,Given that I will code in Pycharm later, I would like to ask what the problem is.
Is there a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I saw that in your `declare` statement you are missing a closing quotation mark.

Comment: Because there are other variables that I haven't shown you yet,I just found that I updated the code in Pycharm to the server and found that pycharm showed that the synchronization was successful. However, the code on the server is still in the old version, and the configuration server is executed according to the online tutorial, so there should be no errors.

Comment: The new problem I encountered resolved that My mapping was not correct

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so, please update the question and answer, so that other people can benefit from it too.

Comment: no ，the problem about environment variable is not solved,i still need help.

Comment: Can you please explain the question then? What exactly are you doing, what do you expect, and what actually happens?